# jquery, js, jsp: //make text inside inputbox (or any other idea/suggestion beside input box) clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```html
<input id= "eurl" type="text" name="eurl" readonly>
```

I have a input box which is dynamic (meaning I am getting values in text box from DB), right now the value inside text box are text (they are not responsive). What I was trying to get is make any text inside my textbox as a link (clickable). Also please consider that it does not have to be just  inputbox, is there anyway that I can make text as a link.
[image]  //make text(coming form db) inside inputbox clickable/act as a url
.

Comment: this is not possible, this is already asked, here is the link for previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060055/link-in-input-text-field

Comment: what other ways can I make a text as a link( what about lable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so sure of what end result you want but you can try to wrap your input box within a `<a>` tag that has a href to your link.

```
<a href="http://google.com">
   <input type="text" value="google.com" />
</a>
```

To get the value from DB, you will need additional codes. For instance in PHP:

```
foreach($data as $value){
   echo '<a href="'+$value['link']+'">
           <input type="text" value="'+$value['link']+'" />
         </a>'
}
```

Or you can do additional Javascript to map the values. You can even push the href in to the element attribute.

```
<a id="justALink">
   <input id="inputWithLink" type="text" value="google.com" />
</a>

<script>
   document.getElementById('justALink').setAttribute('href', 'http://google.com');
</script>
```

Or push in by getting the text input value:

```
var inputLink = document.getElementById('inputWithLink').value;
document.getElementById('justALink').setAttribute('href', inputLink);
```

Comment: my values comes from DB, is there anyway to store values from db to href?

Comment: I have edited the answer for more details. Just the brief ideas, as I do not know how you retrieve the data. On page load from PHP, or AJAX request?

Comment: Popdroid you are toooooo awesome man, I have been working on this week ,finally got it!. thx for such a wonderful help. this worked perfect for me :var inputLink = document.getElementById('inputWithLink').value;
document.getElementById('justALink').setAttribute('href', inputLink);